# Mysql loop in the table for certain values

Tags: mysql, loops

For testing purposes, my table records certain arrivals and departures (Booking type = 'arrival' or 'departure').

Let us assume that the structure is:

```
ID (PK), RFID, Date, Time, Booking type
```

I would like to find out who forgot to register his/her own *last* departure in a given date.

My idea is to find out whether the last (highest ID?) booking for each of the RFID (persons) equals to 'departure'.

Would anybody be so kind to give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

edit: Example with data

> 1, 12345, 20.05.2018, 10:00, arrival
>
> 2, 44444, 20.05.2018, 10:30, arrival
>
> 3, 12345, 20.05.2018, 14:00, departure
>
> 4, 44444, 20.05.2018, 15:00, departure
>
> 5, 44444, 20.05.2018, 16:00, arrival
>
> 6, 12345, 20.05.2018, 17:00, arrival
>
> 7, 44444, 20.05.2018, 19:00, departure

The user **12345** forgot to record his "last" departure of the day. I would like him/her to be shown (as I would like to pipe the output for other purposes).

Comment: Can there be more than one arrival/departure pair in a given date?

Comment: Yes, there can be more.

Comment: You should show some sample data which explains what you want.  I see a contradiction in your question.

Comment: I just edited the post. I hope my question will be clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to know if whether or not the last entry of the day for each user were a departure, then you may try this:

```
SELECT t1.RFID
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT RFID, MAX(Time) AS max_time
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Date = '2018-05-20'
    GROUP BY RFID
) t2
    ON t1.RFID = t2.RFID AND t1.Time = t2.max_time
WHERE
    t1.Date = '2018-05-20'
    t1.booking_type = 'arrival';
```

The strategy here is to isolate the latest record for each user on a given day, and then check the booking type for that record.

Comment: Hi Tim, brilliant, why thinking to a loop if I could have done such a join? 

The only thing is that I get a syntax error if I use t2.booking_type = 'arrival'. 

Should it be t1.booking_type = 'arrival' ?

Thanks again

Comment: @flapane Yes, you have it right.  It should be referring to `t1.booking_type`.  The `t2` subquery doesn't have that column.

Comment: Thanks again, your example is really appreciated.